# showing a css component for a specified number of seconds

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi i'm writing a simple popup called popup-box i want it to be shown for only 10 sec and after this period it will be hide so how to do it any idea please

here's my code :

css code:

```
/* Styles for game over popup */
   #popup {
font-family: 'Orbitron', serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: 700;     
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #fff;

color: #222;

position: absolute;   
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;

background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;          

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;}

    #popup h1 {
font-weight: 400;}

    #popup-box {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background: #ccc url(../images/popup_bg.jpg);

border-radius: 10px;

position: relative;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #333;

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    }

    #popup-box small {
font-size: .6em;
    }
      /***** Styles to hide the popup box ******/
    #popup.hide {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
visibility: hidden;     
       }
   #popup.hide #popup-box{
margin-top: -800px;
    }
```

Html code :

```
        <section id="popup"  class="hide">

     <div id="popup-bg"></div>

     <div id="popup-box">
               Cards are laid out in a grid face down,
       and players take turns flipping pairs of cards over.
       On each turn, the player will first turn one card over, 
       then a second. If the two cards match, 
       the player scores one point,
       the two cards are removed from the game, 
       and the player gets another turn. 
       If they do not match, the cards are turned back over.


         </div>


   </section>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml

Comment: You are going to need some JavaScript to achieve this. Do you have any code written yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it can be done with:

```
$("#popup").fade​In(500, function​​​​​​​() {
    $(this).delay(10000).fadeOut(500)
})​;​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q8xMk/

Comment: It should. Don't forget to set `display: none;` style to `#popup` block.

Answer (score 1):

Add this anywhere in the HTML:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("popup-box").style.display = "none" }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

`setTimeout(f, t)` basically calls the function `f` after *t* seconds. Since it's called on `window.onload`, it does so *t* seconds after the page *fully* loads.